# Distinguish between value invalid and value not given in Angular2 control

Tags: validation, angular

I have a control that should accept only numbers, and I want to give the user a hint why the control is marked red:

```
<label>Version</label>
<input name="version" #version="ngModel" required type="number" pInputText [(ngModel)]="item.version"/>
<small class="field-validation-error" [hidden]="version.valid">
  Not a number
</small>
```

The problem is, the message is shown when there's no value in the control. This is invalid, but I want to show 'Value is required' message then. I've tried:

```
    <small class="field-validation-error" [hidden]="version.value">
      Value is required
    </small>
```

but then, the 'Value is required' message is displayed event if the value is provided, but is not a numer.

How can I distinguish between value not give, and value given, but invalid, using `ngModel` binding?

Answer (score 1):

What about :

```
<label>Version</label>
<input name="version" #version="ngModel" pattern="[0-9]*" required type="number" pInputText [(ngModel)]="item.version"/>

<small class="field-validation-error" *ngIf="version.control.dirty && version.control.hasError('required')">
    Value is required
</small>

<small class="field-validation-error" *ngIf="version.control.dirty && version.control.hasError('pattern')">
    Not a number
</small>
```

Comment: I get an error 'Value is required' even if the value is present, but not a number

Comment: But if you have an  `input type="number"` you can't type something else than number, no ? Else you can go on with the `pattern` attribute

Comment: With hasError('pattern'), it works. With hasError('number'), not. Tested on Chrome.

Comment: It seems that only required, minlength, maxlength and pattern are recognized by angular 2 for now ([sources](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html)). I update my answer

Answer (score 0):

I'd just go with

```
  <small class="field-validation-error" [hidden]="item.version.value">
      Value is required
    </small>
```

just check the real value instead the value of the input element

Comment: The problem is, when the value is not valid, it was not set and the 'value is required' instead of 'not a number' was displayzed

Comment: Well if the value is not set yet it should show "Value is required" no?